# How to get the count of columns in each column family in HBASE

Tags: count, nosql, hdfs, hbase, column-family

How to get the count of columns in each column family in HBASE.

I have a table_name T, and columnfamily 'f' and 'm', have 10 columns each. how to count the number of columns in each column family.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can add any arbitrary column to any row, the only way is to scan then entire table and count the columns. HBase does not keep schema/metadata on column level.